# How do i save notifications in phpmysql database for several users without overloading my database records

Tags: php, mysql, join, backend, message

I fear that i can easily create reptition in my database while trying to ensure that all users in my db can view the same message. The problem is i need to be able to send from my admin area a message and have all users get notified and also have the option to mark messages as read. i know i ought to create two tables but how to write the sql command to generate the message for all users is becoming frustrating. this might probably be one easy task but i need help

i tried creating two tables in my Db. Notification and has__notify.
the notification saves the message with its title and date created while (has__notify) on the other hand contains columns like notificationID(foreign key), userID(foreign key)- to know which user has read the message, dateRead.
however, i think my implementation is wrong cause, i am a bit confused already.

Comment: I think you made the right choices with those two tables.

Comment: _Side note:_ There's no such thing as a "phpmysql database". It's just a "mysql database".

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you very much for the help i think i just needed some expert to tell me i was doing well. I eventually figured out the whole thing.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Oh! i think i accidentally wrote that (phpmysql database) Thank you however for the correction and the interest in my question. i hope i can still count on your help in the nearest future. God bless you all

Answer (score 0):

By default a table would never be locked during insert. If you want be sure that data was stored you can use a transactions.

Comment: Did you answer the wrong question, or did you just misunderstand it? This doesn't in any way address the question at hand.